# TinyMCE and UpdatePanel - Saving

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, updatepanel, tinymce

I'm trying to get TinyMCE ( a single editor) working with an UpdatePanel. I can get the content using:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function() {
    var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
    alert(ed.getContent());
});
```

I can also reload the editor with (on end request)

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function() {
    setTimeout('tinyMceInit()', 800);
});
```

The problem is saving the contents, they always go back to default when the page posts back. I've tried ed.triggerSave() and a few others, but nothing seems to work.

Has anyone had this working?

Comment: I've also tried with:
    setTimeout(function(){
        tinyMceInit();
        var ed = tinyMCE.activeEditor;
        alert(messageContent);
        ed.onInit.add(function(ed2) {
            alert('o:'+messageContent);
            ed2.setContent(messageContent);
        });
    }, 800);

Which shows the alert correctly but doesn't set the content. Everything seems to say this should work.

Answer (score 0):

When the pages reloads totaly then your contents are lost. You need to save them in a db and get them from there to set the editors content.